# Struggling with basic limit problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As part of some other proof, I'm trying to show the following:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a \in \overline{A}-A$ (ie. in the closure of A but not in A) so that the function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x-a|}$ is well-defined on $A$. I want to show that the function is continuous everywhere on $A$. Now I went through the usual rigmarole which I'll outline below, but essentially I
am struggling to find a way to bound the $\frac{1}{|y-a|}$ that you'll see in the attempted proof below. I seem to have forgotten how to deal with cases like this from single-variable calculus.

**Attempt:**
Fixing any $x \in A$ and given any $\epsilon$, we want to be able to bound, for any other $y \in A$ (subject to that $y$ being in the ball defined by the $\delta$ we're trying to determine),

$$|f(y)-f(x)|=\left|\frac{1}{|y-a|}-\frac{1}{|x-a|}\right|=$$

$$\frac{1}{|x-a||y-a|}\left||y-a|-|x-a|\right|\leq\frac{1}{|x-a||y-a|}|y-x|$$
so that we have it in the nice form where if we require $\delta$ to be the $min(\epsilon|x-a|, B)$, where $B$ is that something I'm missing to put a bound on the $\frac{1}{|y-a|}$, then we are done. Can someone help point out what I need?
Roughly, it seems clear to me that I need to show $|y-a|>C$ for some $C$ that depends only on $x, \epsilon, a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition is that if $y$ is close to $x$, then $|y-a|$ is close to $|x-a|$.

Formally, to obtain $|y-a| > C$ as you mentioned in your last sentence,

$$|y-a| \ge |x-a| - |x-y| \ge |x-a| - \delta.$$

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! So, just to confirm then, we'll require that (there are doubtless many other and more elegant ways, but I want to confirm that this works) the $B$ I mention above to be, say, $B= |x-a|/2$, and then modify my other argument to that $min$ to be $\frac{|x-a|^2\epsilon}{2}$ so that I can continue your string of inequalities and have $|y-a| \geq |x-a|/2$ and then I'll get the desired result?

Comment: @1729_SR looks ok to me

Answer (score 3):

For any $\epsilon\gt0$, and $x\in A$, let $\delta=\min\left(\frac{|x-a|}2,\frac{|x-a|^2}2\epsilon\right)$. If $|y-x|\le\delta$, then
$$
\begin{align}
|y-a|
&\ge|x-a|-|y-x|\tag1\\[3pt]
&\ge|x-a|-\frac{|x-a|}2\tag2\\
&=\frac{|x-a|}2\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: triangle inequality
$(2)$: $|y-x|\le\delta\le\frac{|x-a|}2$
$(3)$: arithmetic

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac1{|x-a|}-\frac1{|y-a|}\right|
&=\frac{|\,|y-a|-|x-a|\,|}{|x-a||y-a|}\tag4\\
&\le\frac{|y-x|}{|x-a|\frac{|x-a|}2}\tag5\\
&\le\epsilon\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: arithmetic
$(5)$: triangle inequality and $(3)$
$(6)$: $|y-x|\le\delta\le\frac{|x-a|^2}2\epsilon$

This says that $\frac1{|x-a|}$ is continuous at any $x\in A$.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the other answer because it came first, but this was very useful to me too. PS: explanations (3) and (4) made me laugh :)